# Get a strange array value

Tags: php, arrays, json

when i load a database single data,it's seems like array,
but i don't know how to get the value in label_values

print_r($results):

```
Array ( [custom_params] => custom_limit="0"|input_label="{\"label_values\":[\"\u9650\u5916\u5e36\",\"\u9650\u5167\u7528\",\"\u9650\u6642\u5546\u54c1\",\"\u514d\u9810\u7d04\",\"\u5373\u8cb7\u5373\u7528\",\"\u672c\u9031\u5f37\u6a94\",\"\u611b\u5fc3\u516c\u76ca\"]}"|repeat_label=""| )
```

json_encode($results):

```
{"custom_params":"custom_limit=\"0\"|input_label=\"{\\\"label_values\\\":[\\\"\\u9650\\u5916\\u5e36\\\",\\\"\\u9650\\u5167\\u7528\\\",\\\"\\u9650\\u6642\\u5546\\u54c1\\\",\\\"\\u514d\\u9810\\u7d04\\\",\\\"\\u5373\\u8cb7\\u5373\\u7528\\\",\\\"\\u672c\\u9031\\u5f37\\u6a94\\\",\\\"\\u611b\\u5fc3\\u516c\\u76ca\\\"]}\"|repeat_label=\"\"|"}
```

tried foreach first lavel:

```
foreach($results as $k=>$v){
    echo $v;
}
```

get:

```
custom_limit="0"|input_label="{\"label_values\":[\"\u9650\u5916\u5e36\",\"\u9650\u5167\u7528\",\"\u9650\u6642\u5546\u54c1\",\"\u514d\u9810\u7d04\",\"\u5373\u8cb7\u5373\u7528\",\"\u672c\u9031\u5f37\u6a94\",\"\u611b\u5fc3\u516c\u76ca\"]}"|repeat_label=""|
```

but don't know to get value then...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have only one element in your array initially then what else you want?

Comment: How are you populating the `$result` variable? Can we see that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$results['custom_params']` is a pipe-delimited list of `key=value` pairs, so you need to split it up. And the `input_label` value there is JSON, which you can parse with `json_decode`.

Also, you need to remove the backslashes before the quotes in the value.

```
$custom_params = explode('|', $results['custom_params']);
foreach ($custom_params as $param) {
    if (preg_match('/^input_label="(.*)"$/', $param, $match)) {
        $input_label = json_decode(str_replace('\"', '"', $match[1]), true);

        $label_values = $input_label['label_values'];
        break;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/tdhEwL)

Comment: ,thanks for reply,but when tried export values,echo $input_label or echo $label_values,nothing happen

Comment: The backslashes before the quotes were causing a problem, I've fixed it. See the demo.